# 'à' french character display using JSON shows error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sql-server, french

I have a french character (à) in my JSON String 'd'instruments cordes à'. But the (à) character shows JSON error when displaying. I want to display the exact character in my UI.

Comment: please show us some code

Comment: How do you “display” the à?

Comment: à is considered a special character in JSON.

Comment: From my experience, you can just use special characters, in JSON as long as they don’t include a \ or "

Comment: Can you include your actual JSON string? There should be no issue with using that character. Are you sure the issue isn't the single quote?

Comment: `["634149","d'instruments cordes u00E0","America"] `  . The Actual string stored in database is `'d'instruments cordes à'`

Answer (score 0):

You really should provide more details. As of now, it's unclear whether you are generating or parsing your JSON in the database.

Regardless, below is a short sample demonstrating that "à" is not a special character in any way. Compare the code below with yours, and especially pay attention to the difference between `varchar` and `nvarchar`. I think that's where your problem is.

```
declare @j nvarchar(max);

declare @t table (
    Id int,
    Value nvarchar(100),
    Country varchar(50)
);

insert into @t (Id, Value, Country)
values
    (634149, N'd''instruments cordes à', 'America');

-- Shows data in the table
select * from @t;

set @j = (
    select *
    from @t t
    for json path, without_array_wrapper
);

-- Shows generated JSON
select @j as [GeneratedJSON];

-- Shows JSON query output
select *
from openjson(@j) with (
    Id int '$.Id',
    Value nvarchar(100) '$.Value',
    Country varchar(50) '$.Country'
) j;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your page contains the following meta tag to support international characters.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```